Is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation?
Is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation?

Acts 16:31 - They replied, “Believe in the Lord Jesus and you will be
saved, you and your household.”


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this is different.

This site only permits one significant question at once.  If you wish to ask both question, ask it as a separate question (but not together).

Please take our Tour and then search for questions that have already been asked and answered on these two points: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

To properly understand the answers you will receive, I suggesr a lot of thought about the meaning of "believe in", and how it might differ from "believe that [something is true]".

@Chance. The biblical Jesus tied having eternal life with knowing the true God (his God, the Father) and the one whom he sent (Jesus Christ). John 17:3.

No. Read James chapter 2.


Is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation?

That depends upon what you mean by "believing in".
Consider a non-religious analogy.
I tell you "Smoking is very bad for your health; I want you to quit.".
There are (at least) two ways of believing in me:

You agree that I am correct, but you are handling too many problems at the moment and now is not a good time to quit.
You incorporate my truth into your life and you immediately quit (without taking "one last puff").

Salvation requires the latter kind of belief.

(-1) Zero exegesis, or engagement with any texts - this is a purely opinion based answer.

@Stevecanhelp — Doesn't that apply to most of the other answers too? It's difficult to answer properly when the question doesn't define its terms. Vague or ambiguous questions deserve similar answers, or better yet, none at all until they are sufficiently improved. The question has 4 downvotes so far, and 3 votes-to-close for 3 different reasons. After 36 hours, why is this question still open?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What does scripture say?
Romans 10:9-13

9 because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and
believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be
saved. 10 For with the heart one believes and is justified, and with
the mouth one confesses and is saved. 11 For the Scripture says,
“Everyone who believes in him will not be put to shame.” 12 For there
is no distinction between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord is Lord of
all, bestowing his riches on all who call on him. 13 For “everyone who
calls on the name of the Lord will be saved.”

Verse 9 says you will be saved if one:

Believes in their heart
Confesses with their mouth

Verse 13 says:

Call on the name of the Lord and you will be saved

Scripture also says:
John 3:16

16 “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son,
that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal
life.


Believe and you will have eternal life

But scripture also says:
James 2:19

19 You believe that God is one; you do well. Even the
demons believe—and shudder!


Demons believe

There is a large difference in these verse in the form of the word Lord.

he to whom a person or thing belongs, about which he has the power of
deciding; master, lord;
used a. universally, of the possessor and disposer of a thing, the
owner
one who has control of the person, the master
the sovereign, prince, chief

For the Christian, salvation comes because Jesus is Lord. (if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord)
So, the question might arise: what kind of belief do you have?

Intellectual assent: Are we simply agreeing with the facts about Jesus?
Like His existence and that He taught things?
Saving assent: Do we trust and rely on Jesus for
salvation, thus producing repentance and commitment?
Living assent: Is our faith demonstrated through actions
and works?


"For there is no distinction between Jew and Greek; for the same Lord is Lord of all, bestowing his riches on all who call on him" seems to indicate to me that it is not even necessary to believe in Jesus? I'll happily go along with that but I can imagine not everyone does.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I like that your profile picture is a Mandelbrot set. I agree with that. Jesus is Lord of all, but not everyone believes he is Lord. John 14:6

Jesus said to him, “I am the way, and the truth, and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.


This is kind of like asking, after your father warns you and tells you to listen to your mother, is listening to your mother enough for your mother and father to both be pleased with you?
You see the answer depends on what you mean by listening. If you mean to simply listen with your ear, then probably not. But if by listening you mean to listen so as to obey her instruction then that would fulfill what your father had in mind. When someone tells you to listen to someone else who has authority over you they mean for you to obey their lawful instructions.
This applies to the concept of belief with respect to Jesus. Jesus is Lord of heaven and Earth. You aren't to believe him to simply believe him, but being that he is the king of cosmos you are to obey him. The point of the instruction for belief isn't belief in and of itself but to believe for the purpose of obedience. Obedience is what is desired and not simply belief.
This is why Jesus says,

46 “Why do you call me ‘Lord, Lord,’ and not do what I tell you? Luke 6:46

And,

21 “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven. Matthew 7:21

And,

26 And everyone who hears these words of mine and does not do them will be like a foolish man who built his house on the sand. Matthew 7:26

Jesus states in clear terms that our status within the love of Christ is conditioned on whether or not we keep his commandments:

10 If you keep my commandments, you will abide in my love, just as I have kept my Father’s commandments and abide in his love. John 15:10

Consider Jesus's parable of final judgment (sheep vs goats) in Matthew 25:31-46. The only difference between those who entered eternal life and those who didn't isn't what they believed but what they did - whether or not they served Christ by serving the least of his brothers.

31 “When the Son of Man comes in his glory, and all the angels with him, then he will sit on his glorious throne. 32 Before him will be gathered all the nations, and he will separate people one from another as a shepherd separates the sheep from the goats. 33 And he will place the sheep on his right, but the goats on the left. 34 Then the King will say to those on his right, ‘Come, you who are blessed by my Father, inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of the world. 35 For I was hungry and you gave me food, I was thirsty and you gave me drink, I was a stranger and you welcomed me, 36 I was naked and you clothed me, I was sick and you visited me, I was in prison and you came to me.’ 37 Then the righteous will answer him, saying, ‘Lord, when did we see you hungry and feed you, or thirsty and give you drink? 38 And when did we see you a stranger and welcome you, or naked and clothe you? 39 And when did we see you sick or in prison and visit you?’ 40 And the King will answer them, ‘Truly, I say to you, as you did it to one of the least of these my brothers, you did it to me.’
41 “Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart from me, you cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels. 42 For I was hungry and you gave me no food, I was thirsty and you gave me no drink, 43 I was a stranger and you did not welcome me, naked and you did not clothe me, sick and in prison and you did not visit me.’ 44 Then they also will answer, saying, ‘Lord, when did we see you hungry or thirsty or a stranger or naked or sick or in prison, and did not minister to you?’ 45 Then he will answer them, saying, ‘Truly, I say to you, as you did not do it to one of the least of these, you did not do it to me.’ 46 And these will go away into eternal punishment, but the righteous into eternal life.” Matthew 25:31-46

Understanding Biblically that proper belief and faith, with respect to the Lord of all creation, naturally means to obey helps us make sense of James when he says:

17 So also faith by itself, if it does not have works, is dead. James 2:17
24 You see that a person is justified by works and not by faith alone.
James 2:24
26 For as the body apart from the spirit is dead, so also faith apart from works is dead. James 2:26

This is also why Paul says that the purpose of his grace and apostleship is to bring about the obedience of faith:

...we have received grace and apostleship to bring about the obedience of faith for the sake of his name among all the nations
-Romans 1:5

Further Paul warns that our fate depends upon whether we order our lives in accordance with the Spirit of God in whom we believe:

12 So then, brothers, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live according to the flesh. 13 For if you live according to the flesh you will die, but if by the Spirit you put to death the deeds of the body, you will live. Romans 8:12-13

And accordingly, Paul describes this fearful end of those who do not obey:

7 ...the Lord Jesus is revealed from heaven with his mighty angels 8 in flaming fire, inflicting vengeance on those who do not know God and on those who do not obey the gospel of our Lord Jesus. 2 Thessalonians 1:7-8

So then, is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation?
Well, yes, if we understand that given the very high position of authority of the Lord Jesus Christ, the idea of belief in this context is most certainly to believe so that we obey.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@curiousdannii, why do you remove comments that request clarification or suggest improvements?

When it's a whole conversation I don't usually look to keep just some of them. You can read all the conversation in the chat room.

@curiousdannii, but sometimes, even on this board, you do remove some parts of the discussion and leave the beginning part alone. Also on this board you leave much longer discussions un molested. It just looks very much like unequal treatment to completely sequester some comments. Partially prune others and then leave much greater offenders untouched.

The mods don't see everything, a lot of the time we're just responding to flags. And then it's a judgement call. The comments aren't "completely sequestered", they've been moved to chat. Feel free to flag any comments you think are other greater offenders. :)

@curiousdannii, May I  request that in the future as a matter of judicial prudence that you only remove comments that strictly violate policy and do not remove comments that do actually request clarification or suggest improvement just as the comments are intended.  I've seen too many times good helpful comments even by people who have nothing to do with the discussion get swept away because of a flag on an adjacent comment. I know its easier to do it the other way, but it is also less just.

Long comment chains are violations of policy all by themselves. If you want to dispute any comment removals then please do so on [meta]. I will stop responding here now, thanks.

Is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation?  No.
The demons know exactly who Jesus Christ is, and this is evidenced by the numerous times when he drove them out.  Oh yes, they believe who Jesus Christ is. They also believe that there is only one God, and that Jesus is God incarnate, who existed prior to coming to earth and was eternally begotten, not created.

You believe that there is one God.  Good!  Even the demons believe that - and shudder. (James 2:19)

Why do the demons shudder?  Because they know what awaits them.
A better question might be, what does it mean to believe in Jesus Christ?
As for the question about Jesus being born or created, this subject has been asked and answered many times in  Biblical Hermeneutics. For example:
What does the word "prototokos" mean in Colossians 1:15?

There is a difference between belief and faith. Faith is counted as righteousness, but merely believing is not.
According to Strongs - pistis ("faith") for the believer is "God's divine persuasion" – and therefore distinct from human belief (confidence)
This means faith is something that is planted by God himself into humans and not something that humans have the ability of developing on their own.
Humans can develop confidence, knowledge, understanding on their own, but faith is entirely separate and of God as a gift to those who choose to believe.
This is evident in studying the disciples who behaved and acted without faith, although they believed. Their faith was so small that they accomplished nothing on their own, until they received the Gift from God at Pentecost that gave them faith to overcome. It changed everyone's behavior. No more talking about who was the greatest, no more failures trying to do the miracles that Jesus told them to do.
Faith is increased by hearing the word of God and by His Spirit for those that accept Him.
For those that don't accept Him, hearing does nothing, as I'm sure we have all witnessed in real time.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I thought we did move it to chat.

Yes, believing in Jesus Christ is enough for salvation.

For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life. For God sent not his Son into the world to condemn the world; but that the world through him might be saved. He that believeth on him is not condemned: but he that believeth not is condemned already, because he hath not believed in the name of the only begotten Son of God. And this is the condemnation, that light is come into the world, and men loved darkness rather than light, because their deeds were evil. - John 3:16-19

It is as clearly laid out here in John chapter 3 as anywhere in the New Testament.  There are two categories of position before God into which every living person falls: condemned or not condemned.  There is one criteria determining which category is occupied by whom: Believing in the name of the only begotten Son of God, which is Jesus the Christ.
Believing triggers a move from 'condemned' to 'not condemned' because the light (Jesus) that has come into the world is received rather than rejected in favor of darkness.

That was the true Light, which lighteth every man that cometh into the world. He was in the world, and the world was made by him, and the world knew him not. He came unto his own, and his own received him not. But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name: Which were born, not of blood, nor of the will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God.

In God's eternal economy there is an already completed salvation which He has offered as a gift to all humanity through His only begotten Son.  In our temporal economy each individual must receive this Son, this gift of salvation, in order to be permanently moved from condemned to not condemned:

There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit. - Romans 8:1

The pattern of the one who is not condemned is 'walking after the Spirit' rather than 'after the flesh'.  The only way to walk after the Spirit is to have the Spirit of God dwelling within:

So then they that are in the flesh cannot please God. But ye are not in the flesh, but in the Spirit, if so be that the Spirit of God dwell in you. Now if any man have not the Spirit of Christ, he is none of his. And if Christ be in you, the body is dead because of sin; but the Spirit is life because of righteousness. - Romans 8:8-10

And the only way for the Spirit of God to dwell within is to believe on the name of the Lord Jesus Christ.  The indwelling Spirit is that "power to become children of God" that is given to those who "receive him", who "believe on his name" (referring back to John 1).
The life that walks after the indwelling Spirit, in opposition to the flesh, is the life that is being sanctified by that Spirit and the end result of that sanctification is resurrection and glorification.  The work of preparing salvation is all of God in Christ.  The work of sanctification unto salvation is all of God in the Spirit of Christ.  The work of resurrection unto glory is all of God in Christ as well.
The responsibility of man is to first believe in Jesus.  Then and only then will that one be enabled to walk according to the Spirit that sanctifies.  This work of God by sanctification of the Spirit is promised to be brought to completion by Him without fail (Philippians 1:6, John 6:39-40).  Therefore it is enough to believe in Jesus to be saved.

What and if dispensation is given to those who may have never heard or who are prior to an age of accountability is a theological rather than an hermeneutic question.  Hermeneutically speaking one must believe in the Lord Jesus Christ in order to be saved.

Very nice answer. +1

Answer
Jesus Christ Himself says that just believing in Jesus Christ is not enough for salvation!
(To many, this is an emotionally loaded question. So this is an effort to provide an as objective and accurate answer as is possible.)
Explanation
Let us listen to Jesus’s opinion:

“Not everyone who keeps saying to me, 'Lord, Lord,' will get
into the kingdom from heaven, but only the person who keeps doing
the will of my Father in heaven” (Mat 7:21).

The people who call “Lord, Lord” to Jesus are the people who believe in Him. They simply believe in Him and claim that “no works” for salvation is required.
But Jesus doesn’t have any doubt and He pulls no punches when He says that “doing the Will of God” is required for salvation.

“For whoever does the will of My Father in Heaven, that one is My
brother and sister and mother” (Mat 12:50).

Miracle Workers
The people who believe in Jesus without any works are not ordinary people, they are powerful evangelists who perform miracles in Jesus’s name:

“Many will say to me on that day, 'Lord, Lord, we prophesied in
your name, drove out demons in your name, and performed many
miracles in your name, didn't we?'” (Mat 7:22).

So, they are powerful people who did all those wonderful things in Jesus’s name. They believed in Jesus sincerely.
Even Jesus acknowledges them in a positive way:

“But Jesus said, "Don't stop him, because no one who works a miracle
in my name can slander me soon afterwards” (Mar 9:39).

So these are powerful miracle workers and evangelists who believe in Jesus.
Then what is the problem?

“And then I will declare to them, I never knew you; "depart from
Me, those working lawlessness!" (Mat 7:23).

So, these are evangelists who proclaimed the name of Jesus, worked miracles, drove out demons from people and prophesied, all in the name of Jesus!
But there is only one problem; they preached faith alone, grace alone and no works. They taught that Jesus Christ nailed to the cross the holy commandments of His Father.
Thus they promoted anomia or lawlessness.
Good Works Required
Both faith and good works are demanded by none other than Jesus Himself:
Faith alone will not do:

“And why do you call Me Lord, Lord (faith), and do not do
what I say (good works)?” (Luke 6:46).

What happens to those who have both faith and good works, according to Jesus?

“Everyone coming to Me (faith) and hearing My Words, and doing
them (good works), I will show you to whom he is like: He is like a
man building a house, who dug and deepened, and laid a foundation on
the rock. And a flood having occurred, the stream burst against that
house and could not shake it, for it had been founded on the rock”
(Luke 6:47-48).

What happens to people who have only faith in Jesus but argue that no works required?

“But he who heard (faith alone) and did not perform (no
works), he is like a man having built his house on the earth without a
foundation, on which the stream burst, and it immediately fell; and
the ruin of that house was great.” (Luke 6:49).

The Parable of the Ten Virgins
(Matthew 25:1-13)
Though people may interpret the parable of the Ten Virgins in different ways, one thing is sure: mere belief will not save a believer in the critical moment of his life!
According to this parable, all the ten virgins took their lamps. They believed in the Bridegroom and knew that when He comes He will take all of them to the wedding feast.
But the Bridegroom delayed. They all slept. At midnight, the Bridegroom came. However, five of the virgins were shut out, even though they believed in the Bridegroom!
So, all the ten virgins had faith/belief in the Bridegroom.
But only five of them were wise to take oil with them.
I will not interpret what oil symbolizes. But this parable proves that “faith alone” will not save a believer.
Scriptural Definition of Belief
People get emotionally upset on this contentious topic, often unnecessarily, because there is confusion over the definition of what belief is.
So, what is belief? Does it mean simply to know the truth and go one’s usual way without doing anything about it?
For example, Paul says:

“One person believes that he may eat anything” (Rom 14:2).

Now, does it mean that the person, who believes he may eat anything, will eat only vegetables? Not at all. We all take action based on our conviction/belief.
So, belief entails action based on such belief. This is the Scriptural definition of believing.
Jesus Christ says:

“you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart, and with all
your soul" and with all your mind, "and with all your strength. This
is the first commandment." (Mar 12:30).

[Jesus is talking about the first 4 of the Commandments]
This is possible only on faith; only by believing because no one can see God or Jesus Christ!

“And the second is like this, "You shall love your neighbor as
yourself." There is not another commandment greater than these” (verse
31).

[Jesus is talking about the second 6 of the Commandments (Rom 13:9)]
Here comes the action part of our belief when we love our neighbors (whom we definitely see) and do good to them. This involves good works!
I am sure no one will oppose this idea; yet this topic is unnecessarily so contentious. This amazes me.
So, Apostle John asks:

“For the one not loving his brother whom he has seen (good
works), how is he able to love God whom he has not seen
(faith/belief)?” (1 John 4:20).

So, a believer cannot have a living faith or active belief unless he has good works!
Apostle Paul also says the same thing:

“because it was granted to you on behalf of Christ not only to
believe in Him (faith), but also to suffer on His behalf (good deeds)” (Phlp 1:29).

The suffering of a believer comes from his fellow human beings who are not themselves believers. Yet the believer has to “love his enemies” and suffer persecution.

“For which cause I also suffer these things (good works).
But I am not ashamed, for I know whom I have believed
(faith)” (2 Tim 1:12).

So, faith always should be accompanied by good works.

“Faithful is the Word, and concerning these things I desire you
strongly to affirm that the ones believing God should take thought
to maintain good works. These things are good and profitable to
men” (Titus 3:8).

Apostle Jude also says the same thing:

“Having made all haste to write to you about the common salvation,
beloved, I had need to write to you to exhort you to contend
earnestly (good works) for the faith (belief) once delivered to
the saints” (Jude 1:3).

Was Apostle John a Liar?
So, was Apostle John lying when he said, God so loved the world that He gave His only Son that whoever believes in Him should not perish but have eternal life?
John himself says:

“If anyone says, I love God (faith/belief), and hates his brother
(no good works), he is a liar” (1 John 4:20).

The Scriptural faith or belief doesn’t go without good works.

“Who is the one overcoming the world (good works) except the one who
believes that Jesus is the Son of God?” (1 John 5:5).


“And this is His commandment, that we should believe the name of
His Son, Jesus Christ, and love one another (good works), even as
He gave command to us” (1 John 3:23).

So, Scripturally, “believe” means to take good and proper action in the direction of one’s belief/faith.
Conclusion

“Faith that doesn't lead us to do good deeds is all alone and
dead!” (James 2:17;CEV).


"And, behold, I am coming quickly, and My reward is with Me, to
give to each as his work is" (Rev 22:12).


"So that, my beloved, ...., WORK out your own salvation with fear
and trembling" (Phlp 2:12).


"And I saw the dead, the small and the great, standing before God. And
books were opened. And another Book was opened, which is the Book of
Life. And the dead were judged out of the things written in the books,
according to their works. And the sea gave up the dead in it. And death and hell gave up the dead in them. And they were each judged
according to their works" (Rev 20:12-13).


So, you're saying that the apostle John was lying when he wrote, “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have eternal life." Instead, John should have written, “For God so loved the world, that he gave his only Son, that whoever merely believes in him will still perish and not have eternal life." Thanks for clearing this up!

Paul says, “Faithful is the Word, and concerning these things I desire you strongly to affirm that the ones believing God should take thought to maintain good works. These things are good and profitable to men” (Titus 3:8). So to believe in Jesus means to maintain good works. “They profess to know God, but by their works they deny Him, being abominable and disobedient, and worthless to every good work” (Titus 1:16). “for we are His workmanship, created in Christ Jesus (through belief in Him) unto good works” (Eph 2:10). Believing in Jesus means doing good. These go together.

Exactly! So, the apostle John was indeed a liar. Thanks again!

“And this is his commandment, that we believe in the name of his Son Jesus Christ and love one another (good works), just as he has commanded us” (1 John 3:23). So, no, John didn’t lie.

Oh, whew! Good to hear. :-)

@NepheshRoi One cannot work their salvation out unless it is first within them to work out...to others...in the fear and tremblimg of them missing out.

@MarkVestal – I think I can agree with your comment. Yes, we cannot work our salvation out unless it is first within us to work out…to others. Quite true! But then Scripture says that God has done just that: “Christ; in whom also you, hearing the Word of Truth, the gospel of your salvation, in whom also believing you were sealed with the Holy Spirit of promise” (Eph 1:12-13). So, we agree on this. Then, what is the issue on which people become upset and brawl among themselves, as you can see at the end of each answer, in comments?

@NepheshRoi I believe it is the struggle of coming together in "the unity of the faith" (Eph 4:13).  Satan, the lower case "god of this world" keeps so many blinded from the truth of scripture (2 Cor 4:4). Putting on the "whole armor of God" to fight those wiles of the devil is true spiritual warfare. Eph 6:12 "For we wrestle not against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of the darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness in high places." You and I came to an agreement, so I leave you in peace and grace...unless you wish to discuss further.

A major factor in biblical hermeneutics is understanding the words used in the scriptures. However, a similar factor is recognizing the assumptions that have encrusted the words in our own language over the centuries and the natural drift of our language.
For example, when I hear the word, “Faith,” images of stained-glass windows such as the following materialize in my brain. Faith is something magical possessed by super-saints. Faith is a hundred-dollar word that can be hard to cash.

On the other hand, I can get a better grasp on the word, trust. Trust is a five-dollar word, and it’s something essential to the practical, every-day world of business.
But how do I get someone to trust me, or how do I choose between several competing products or services?  Many people have studied the process of how trust is built in business.

Some, of course, are charlatans and scammers, but the fact is that trust is trust—there’s no qualitative difference, only quantitative. For example, there are some people that I trust a little and some that I trust a lot—even to the point of willingness to trust them with my life.
Trust is built over time. Sometimes, rarely, a person might tell me, “Trust me on this.” Naturally, I’ll want to know why, but I give their reasons greater credibility due to my trust in them.
Several previous answers have already quoted scriptures on trust, so I won’t repeat them. So, is believing in Jesus Christ enough for salvation? Yes, I think it is, but I think trusting Jesus in his competence, sufficiency, and genuine love is a much stronger statement.
And then, as the apostle James clearly pointed out, our trust will also be evidenced in how we live and interact with people. How could it not? Jesus discusses this at length in John 15, including

I am the vine; you are the branches. Whoever abides in me and I in
him, he it is that bears much fruit, for apart from me you can do
nothing. If anyone does not abide in me he is thrown away like a
branch and withers; and the branches are gathered, thrown into the
fire, and burned. – John 15:5,6 ESV


"but I think trusting Jesus in his competence, sufficiency, and genuine love" makes this a great answer.

Agreed. I particularly appreciate the freshness of this answer.

Not me, but Holy Scriptures answer you that faith alone that Christ saves is not enough at all, is dead even, unless you co-work with His grace with conscious efforts:
James 2:18-26:
“Show me your faith without deeds, and I will show you my faith by my deeds. 19 You believe that there is one God. Good! Even the demons believe that—and shudder.
20 You foolish person, do you want evidence that faith without deeds is useless[d]? 21 Was not our father Abraham considered righteous for what he did when he offered his son Isaac on the altar? 22 You see that his faith and his actions were working together, and his faith was made complete by what he did. 23 And the scripture was fulfilled that says, “Abraham believed God, and it was credited to him as righteousness,”[e] and he was called God’s friend. 24 You see that a person is considered righteous by what they do and not by faith alone.
25 In the same way, was not even Rahab the prostitute considered righteous for what she did when she gave lodging to the spies and sent them off in a different direction? 26 As the body without the spirit is dead, so faith without deeds is dead.“
And again, not me, but Scriptures say: "For we are God’s handiwork, created in Christ Jesus to do good works, which God prepared in advance for us to do" (Ephesians 2:10), now think, if we do not do those good works which God prepared for us to do, will we still be saved our God's purpose-resisting idleness notwithstanding? Preposterous to think so.
In fact, what is "salvation"? What is "to be saved", ha? Is not it, as Luke 16:16 says, to take the Kingdom of Heavens by "forcing our way into it", or "taking it by violence" (for βιάζομαι can mean both), and who can on earth deny that those words of the Savior mean our efforts in and together with Him, through faith? Thus, if the one who is the only one to give us salvation, the Savior Himself says that we should press, we should try to conquer by force, will not it be a treason of Him to deny His words and say that we have to do nothing but believe in Him and still be saved?! Dangerous and impermissible naivete, not befitting neither to adults nor even to children to think so!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes!  Not only is it enough for salvation, it (faith alone in Christ alone) is the only path to salvation!
Ephesians 2:8-9

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

Galatians 2:16

Knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law, but by the faith of Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Jesus Christ, that we might be justified by the faith of Christ, and not by the works of the law: for by the works of the law shall no flesh be justified.

Any efforts of our own for salvation only puts us into debt with God.
Romans 4:4-5

Now to him that worketh is the reward not reckoned of grace, but of debt.
5 But to him that worketh not, but believeth on him that justifieth the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness.


To "believe in" is not the same as to "believe that". According to James, even the demons "believe that" Jesus Christ is the son of God and died on a cross for our sins. But they certainly don't "believe in" him.
So to answer your question, yes, it is sufficient to "believe in" him, but what, exactly, does that all entail?

James, writing to the twelve tribes of Israel that were scattered abroad (James 1:1), says nothing about demons believing that "Jesus Christ is the son of God and died on a cross for our sins".  James 2:19 "Thou believest that there is one God; thou doest well: the devils also believe, and tremble."  James was not given the gospel of God's grace, Christ crucified...that was Paul.

@Magmatic Sorry, but the entire passage of James entails nothing else than unless one acts according to faith, this faith alone will avail for nothing, is dead; to the necessary conclusion that only our deeds vivify our faith. “faith in” and “faith that” distinction is not relevant, for in all variations faith without deeds is dead, and in no variations does faith automatically cause deeds without man deciding to freely do faith-led deeds, so both “faith that” and “faith in” (if there is any distinction at all!) are dead without deeds as according to James and common non Calvin-infected sense.

Yes, we need to check what the word believe entails in that context, you have to trust in the teachings of Jesus, and if you trust in the words and teachings of Jesus then you have to practice them which is a very hard feat for most Christians but possible through faith and perseverance. Salvation has a cost and that cost is the way of the cross. You have to deny yourself of worldly things to spend an eternity with God. Believing means believing in his words to practice them
